# Image sprite slide on hover - responsive?

Tags: image, hover, sprite

I want to show another image on hover and due to the layout of the homepage I need to use sprite to do it. I've got it working fine, but I'm using fixed width and height for the container.
You can see my JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mckeene/fhk0byqt/4/

The problem arises when I want to make it responsive. I can use max-width: 100%, but what about the height?

Comment: Sprites are usually used as background-images – but it’s also possible using an image directly: http://jsfiddle.net/fhk0byqt/5/ … sorry, I’m too lazy to explain it further right now.

Comment: Thank you very much. No worries I understand that you found half of the image height, and calculated its proportions versus the width etc.
I will give you points if you want to create an answer :)

Comment: OK, added an answer with explanation (for other users who might want to know how it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this solution is based on the known fact that some properties like `padding-top` and `margin-top`, when given values in percentage, are calculated based on the *width* of an element rather than its height.

Making an element “as high” as required by the known dimensions of a responsive image can be done by using `padding-top` – I used a value of `66.54%` here based on your image’s dimensions (half the image height divided by the width, times 100) to span the container element up to the required height.

Now normally to display the upper half of an image first, and then the second half on hover, I would use absolute positioning – but we can’t use `top` here, since a value in percentage for that property would be based on the height. But luckily, as already mentioned, `margin-top` is one of those properties where percentage is calculated based on the width – so we can use `margin-top: -66.54%` here to “pull” the image up over its container’s padding first to show its upper half, and then double that (`margin-top: -133.1%`) to pull it up even further on hover, to show its lower half.